# Do CSS declarations apply/modify HTML attributes?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where I want to color the text red for html elements with a certain property:

```css
.example1 {
  custom-property: blah
}

.example2 {
/* nothing */
}

[custom-property] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="example1">
some text
</p>

<p class="example2" custom-property="blah">
this is also some text
</p>
```

Here is what I want to happen. All HTML elements that contain an attribute called "custom-property" should have their contents colored red. The first paragraph element is an instance of the class, `example1`, which indicates that all instances should have precisely this "custom-property" field as an attribute. The second paragraph element, on the other hand, has this field explicitly defined for this instance, rather than in the class. So both paragraph elements should have the "custom-property" attribute. (I am aware I am using some object-oriented programming terms, since that is the way I think.)

I use the attribute selector to look for all instances that have "custom-property" as a "field" (i.e. attribute), which both paragraph elements should have. Yet, the selector only selects the instance where "custom-property" is explicitly defined for that element, as shown here:
[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTJFI.png)

So why isn't the first instance being selected by the attribute selector? Surely they both possess the same attribute?

I also believe my question is an inquiry into how HTML and CSS work under the hood and how they interact. (For example, are the "graphics" determined by what is in the HTML or in the CSS? If CSS is what determines the visuals, why is it that I can edit the visuals by editing HTML attributes? Or is it the case that such HTML attributes are turned into "virtual" CSS declarations behind the scenes? I can ask more questions along these lines, but I will keep it constrained to the simpler question posed above.)

Comment: CSS is (1) a selector to select an element (2) propeties;values applied to that element. what you want is (1) apply some properties:values (2) select element based on the properties:values (3) apply *more* properties:values (4) do (2) again <-- we have an infinite loop and this not how CSS should work. What you add to html are attribute that CSS can use as selector

Comment: @TemaniAfif While that does tell me a little something about the intent of CSS as a declarative language, it really does not address my question - namely, whether CSS declarations apply attributes to HTML tags, or if not, whether HTML attributes create CSS declarations (or some other third possibility). Additionally, the ability to apply properties:values and then select those and apply even more would imply a loop, not an infinite loop, and there's a crucial difference - I do not see why this behavior would imply an infinite loop.